# What modeling approach should i use AR, MA, ARMA?

Tags: time-series, self-study, arima, model-selection, acf-pacf

those are my ACF and PACF plots for my time series after two differentiating. I watched a couple of tutorials but I cannot figure out what method I am supposed to use. Also, an interpretation of the plots would be nice.

Using diff() is the only approach not working out for me. I also used decompose(), and tslm(). I am not trying to obtain the best model but rather try many and compare them to each other while learning some stuff along the way.

[image: ACF]
[image: PACF]

The data that I am using is located here

https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/CP0960PLM086NEST

My training model from which the plots are is from 2010 up to 2020

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Like you, I worked with the set from 2010 through 2020--11 years.)  If you difference the series just once, non-seasonally, you stabilize the mean price across time, with rsq = .0003.  I don't see a reason to difference again.  Stabilizing the variance is a separate issue and doesn't require differencing again; what you might try for that is a log transformation.  Seasonally (at lag 12) there's little secular trend that would call for differencing.

Running autocorrelations and partial autocorrelations on an untransformed, singly and non-seasonally differenced series produces many values with a Box-Ljung *p*<.001 and especially a *positive* 0.76 autocorrelation at lag 12.  This would change your interpretation appreciably.  And your work would be cut out for you!

Results are similarly notable with respect to lag 12, and again complex otherwise, when the series tested is first log-transformed.  But I don't find the degree of variability to require such transformation.  The variance in the second half of the period is only 2.05 times as great as in the first.  I believe most analysts would transform only when the variance is at least about 3 times as great in one sub-period as in another.